# Smooks failed to filter source - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class

Tags: spring-boot, edi, smooks, edifact

I am relatively new to EDIFACT/D96A. I am trying to convert from edi using the D96AInterchangeFactory.

Here is what i have:

```
D96AInterchangeFactory factory = D96AInterchangeFactory.getInstance();
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ediContent.getBytes());
UNEdifactInterchange interchange = factory.fromUNEdifact(byteArrayInputStream);
```

on this I get the following error:

```
 org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)
    at .
    .
    .

org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.UNEdifactReader.parse(UNEdifactReader.java:75)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:76)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at
    . .
    org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstanceCreator.createAndSetBean(BeanInstanceCreator.java:296)
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstanceCreator.visitBefore(BeanInstanceCreator.java:241)
        at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.visitBefore(SAXHandler.java:307)
        ... 40 more
```

I read and also added a dependency in d96a for mvel2 and version 2.2.0.Final. Still the same error pops up.

Using JAVA 8
What might i be doing wrong? 
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bumped up the mylin dependency from 1.6 to 1.7.0
works now

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same error by using mvel2 2.3.1.Final.

Comment: no luck. even bumped it up to the latest version.

I notice that, for 13 records, it works fine, its always the 14th that causes the problem no matter what the record

Comment: It's very strange. Are you sure that income edi message fits D96 standards?

Comment: yes
So i have the application on 2 fronts
1- a java 6  spring application on weblogic (everything here works fine, that is the exact same message works here fine)
2- a java 8 sprongboot application (tomcat)  - this is where file which has say greater than 13 14 records throws this particular exception